# Remove Unwanted characters in Output files

Tags: python

I have an issue with the output file where it contains unwanted characters

Current Output:
"('01', '123456789')",Test_1.tt

Required Output:
01,123456789,Test_1.tt

```
try:
    for row in ICOMfilereader:
    row2 = str(row)
    VALIDATED_COHORT1 = 'No'
    VALIDATED_COHORT2 = 'No'
    ACCOUNT = row[0].strip()
    ACCOUNT = ACCOUNT.rjust(9, '0')
    SITE = row[1].strip()
    SITE = SITE.rjust(2, '0')
    SITACC = (SITE,ACCOUNT)
    TYPE = row[10].strip()
    if '1' in TYPE:
         VALIDATED_COHORT1 = 'Yes'
         COHORT1.append(SITACC)
    elif '2' in TYPE:
         VALIDATED_COHORT2 = 'Yes'
         COHORT2.append(SITACC)
except IndexError:
    pass

COHORT1 = sorted(set(COHORT1))
COHORT2 = sorted(set(COHORT2))

for element in COHORT1:
        COHORT1 = (element,'Test_1.tt')
        csvWriter = csv.writer(fo)
        csvWriter.writerow(COHORT1)
```

Comment: Could you format code first? Replace huge indentations with 4 spaces.

Comment: Actually, you need to provide a [mcve]. However, the general solution is "don't write these then!", but I don't think that what you want to hear. For that reason, please read [ask].

Comment: What do you receive in `row` variable? Could you add logging and show what you receive from `ICOMfilereader`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `element` is a tuple. You should unpack it with `*` before writing it (`COHORT1 = (*element,'Test_1.tt')`).

This should take care of your parenthesis and apostrophes. It will also indicate to your csv writer that `SITE` and `ACCOUNT` should be in two separate columns, and the quotes should also disapear.

I hope this helped =)